# Why does this code in C crash? (with pointers)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is an exercise for my C class where the user inputs two integers `a` and `b` and I have to create a function that returns an array that contains all integers between `a` and `b`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int* arrayfromatob(int a,int b,int *p)
{
     int i;
     for(i=0;i<=b-a+1;i++)
            p[i]=a+i;
     return p;
} 

main()
{
      int a,b,*p,i,temp;
      puts("Give two integers:");
      scanf("%d %d",&a,&b);
      if(b<a)
      {
             temp=a;
             a=b;
             b=temp;
      }
      p=(int*)calloc(b-a+1,sizeof(int));
      if(p==NULL)
      {
                 puts("Could not allocate memory");
                 exit(1);
      }
      p=arrayfromatob(a,b,p);
      for(i=0;i<b-a+1;i++)
                printf("Number %d: %d\n",i+1,p[i]);
      free(p);
      system("pause");
}
```

Why does this code crash? (I think it has to do with the free(p); , but I'm not sure...)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, user2202007. Unfortunately, it is hard to help with this question because we don't have anything telling us about the crash. Could you attach the crash log / trace you get from running it?

Comment: Search for memory debuggers. They'll be your best friend when it comes to segfault :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last iteration of the `for` loop in the `arrayfromatob` function tries to access `p[b-a+1]`, which is out of bounds and thus producing ***undefined behavior*** :

```
int* arrayfromatob(int a,int b,int *p)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=b-a+1;i++)   // <-- b-a+2 iterations
        p[i]=a+i;
    return p;
}
```

Additionally, this function doesn't change the pointer itself at all. It just returns the pointer that has been passed to it. You wrote that you *"have to create a function that returns an array that contains all integers between `a` and `b`"*, but your function doesn't create any array, it just assign values to the elements of the array that is passed to it.

Also note that `calloc` zero-initializes the allocated memory, that you are going to rewrite anyway. Simple `malloc` will suffice here. This is how your function should actually look like:

```
// returns the pointer to the newly-created array
// caller should free() this pointer when he's done with it
int* arrayfromatob(int a, int b)
{
    int i, size;
    size = b - a + 1;
    int* p = malloc(size * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        p[i] = a + i;
    return p;
}
```

Comment: @user2202007: Check my answer now. According to your assignment, there should be no `calloc` or `malloc` calls in `main`.

Comment: I'm not used to using pointers yet, so thanks a lot for the extra note! It's really useful!

Comment: Just one more question about your note! When I call malloc in a function, it allocates the needed memory and returns the adress of the first byte, which is attributed to p. Then I retrn p to main. When the function comes to an end, local variable p is destroyed. However, does the memory I allocated in function still usable?

Comment: @user2202007: In `main` you will do: `int* p = arrayfromatob(a, b);` and the memory that `p` will point to will exist till you call `free(p);`.

Answer (score 4):

```
    for(i=0;i<=b-a+1;i++)
        p[i]=a+i;
```

You are accessing `b - a + 2` elements. But you allocated `b - a + 1` elements in:

```
p=(int*)calloc(b-a+1,sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 2):

The following loops past the end of the array:

```
 for(i=0;i<=b-a+1;i++)
```